# Selenium 3.5 IE sendKeys Encoding via Selenium Hub

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer-11

I'm using Selenium 3.5.3 together with the IEDriver x32 on Windows 7 with IE 11 in an UTF-8 encoded Java project. The connection is established via the selenium hub (Docker, Grid Console v.3.5.2). A direct connection to the node works as expected.

When calling `sendKeys` with special characters like:

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL, "a", Keys.LEFT_CONTROL, Keys.BACK_SPACE, "test", Keys.TAB);
```

Selenium will type ?a??test?

With Selenium 2 I did not face this problem and the above code selected the previous input value `(ctrl + a)`, deleted the content, typed in test and pressed the tab key to trigger update events.

(`Keys` is `org.openqa.selenium.Keys`)

I'm not sure how to solve this problem and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This might be because earlier the driver was done by Selenium team and now it is a microsoft driver. So problem may be related to IE driver

Comment: You probably need to enable the native events:  `capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.NATIVE_EVENTS, true);`. Check the code of the first character. If it's `\xE009` then the driver is failing to simulate the control key. If the code is `\x3F`, your class is compiled as ANSI and not UTF8.

Comment: NATIVE_EVE‌NTS are enabled also the encoding of the class seems to be OK.

Comment: It seems to be related to the Selenium Hub (Docker Image Selenium
Grid Console v.3.5.2) with a direct connection to the node the encoding sendKeys works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

To perform actions like this, you shall probably update your code to using [`Actions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) like:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("a").keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys("test").keyDown(Keys.TAB).build().perform();
```

Comment: Sadly, Actions also produces the same result. But thank you for the advice.